# Parse string to DateTime value from telerik datetimepicker

Tags: datetime, telerik

How to parse string "Sat Jan 30 2016 00:29:00 GMT+0300 (Russia TZ 2 Standard Time)" to DateTime?

I have tried reach this by:

```
 DateTime resultDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'K", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
and 
 DateTime resultDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'**Z**", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

and some over methods but all the time error:

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

Foreword, I am try to use date from telerik DateTimePickerFor, 
and I post datetimepicker value as string.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the format in the very first read.

```
string date = (RadDateTimePicker.SelectedDate.Value.Date).ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm tt");
DateTime resultDate = DateTime.Parse(date);
```

This would helps you!!!

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I used DateTime variable in place of string then I POST DateTimePicker data to server.

Comment: Yes, get it as `string` then convert it to `DateTime`, finally post it